# SQL count results and join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have two tables, "analyst" with all names in it and "master" table with all results in it. I am trying to count the number of results per name. Example of tables below:

analyst table

```
id      analyst 
----------------
1       name1
2       name2
3       name3
```

master table

```
id      analyst    result
--------------------------
1       name1      passed
2       name2      failed
3       name1      passed
```

I currently have this below

```
SELECT result, COUNT(*) as Count FROM master GROUP BY Result;
```

Which returns me this:

```
result     Count
-----------------
passed      2
failed      1
```

How can I use join to return the results something like this:

```
analyst     passed     failed
------------------------------
name1        2          0
name2        0          1
name3        0          0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with conditional aggregation. Conditions in `sum` return 1 for true and 0 for false.

```
select analyst, sum(result='passed') as passed, sum(result='failed') as failed
from master
group by analyst
```

If the results should be shown for all the analysts in the analyst table, use

```
select a.analyst
,coalesce(sum(m.result='passed'),0) as passed
,coalesce(sum(m.result='failed'),0) as failed
from analyst a
left join master m on a.analyst=m.analyst
group by a.analyst
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, though this will not return any names that have no results in the master table

Comment: @Anthony Use a LEFT JOIN: `... from analyst left join master using(analyst) ...`

Comment: Note that `SUM` of only NULLs will return NULL (not `0`).